# Laumon's "Sur les modules de Krichever"

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for a copy of the preprint mentioned in the title.

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Comment: Send him an email? His email address can be found easily on the web. (firstname.lastname@math.u-psud.fr)